# Using angularJS, how can I simulate h:commandLink with setPropertyActionListener (POST) in JSF application?

Tags: angularjs, jsf, jsf-2

I integrated AngularJS in a web application (JSF + Facelets + Seam) and now I have to make redirection with POST request which simulate that behavior :

```
<h:commandLink id="openFrais"
               action="/page.xhtml"
               immediate="true"
               title="#{msgs.open}">

    <div class="sprite sprite-folder"/>

    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{collaborateur.collaId}"
                                 target="#{collabHome.collabId}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

In my controller, I try this simple Test :

```javascript
$scope.go = function (n) {
    $scope.rq_1 = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'rest/collabHome/setCollabId',
        data: $.param({
            'collabId': '3214'
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(' sennnd!!!!! ');

        //$location.path  don't work !! i don't use angular Views :'(
        $window.location = "./page.xhtml";
});
```

but when I redirect, I can't keep the conversation with my bean (`@ConversationScoped`) .

PS:  I can't even use AngularFaces.

Comment: Why can't you use AngularFaces?

Answer (score 2):

Your POST request triggered by AngularJS circumvents the JSF engine. Calling $http won't work. Instead, open the developer tools of your browser (the F12 tools) and have a look at the "onclick" handler of the command link. When I tested the code, I found `return myfaces.oam.submitForm('j_id_9','openFrais');` in MyFaces 2.2 and `mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt9'),{'openFrais':'openFrais'},'');return false` in Mojarra 2.2.

In theory, a simple POST should do, too, but you have to make sure to send the hidden fields such as the ViewState.

[image]

BTW, that's why I invented AngularFaces: before long, you're wading knee-deep in implementation-specific JSF code which may break with the next JSF update. Leave that kind of trouble to AngularFaces :).

Comment: i see what u mean , but i have a  problem with primefaces version so i can't use angularFaces .